# Regex ignore the delimiter in parentheses

Tags: php, regex

Good morning,
I need a little of your help.
I need to split the text using REGEX, but to omit the content in parentheses

`preg_match_all('/\((?:[^()]|(?R))+\)|\'[^\']*\'|[^(),]+/', $input_lines, $output_array);`

I have this string:
`Test A, Test B, Test C (data1, data1)`

And pregmatch we do this:

```
0   =>  Test A
1   =>   Test B
2   =>   Test C 
3   =>  (data1, data1)
```

How do I achieve this result?

```
0   =>  Test A
1   =>  Test B
2   =>  Test C (data1, data1)
```

I need to ignore the content in parentheses and separate only the rest.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

This aventually resolved my situation. I tried to use preg split.

`preg_split('/,(?![^(]*\)) /', $input_line);`

Comment: For the given string, and without any more specific requirements or restrictions, I would go with just `explode(',', 'Test A, Test B, Test C (data1, data1)', 3)` instead of regex …

Comment: ```Array
(
    [0] => Test A
    [1] =>  Test B
    [2] =>  Test C (data1, data1), Test D (data1, data1), Test E (data1, data1)
)```

Comment: So what you are trying to say by that now, is that you need to match more than what the example you gave actually showed? Well then give a better example, resp. a _proper_ explanation of what exactly you need to match to begin with.

Comment: I have more strings and you need to divide them by separator (comma) so as to ignore (comma) in parentheses because parenthesis is part of the parameter.

Comment: Teď jsem zkoušel tohle: ```preg_split('/,(?![^(]*\)) /', $input_line);``` a to mi zatím funguje dle potřeb,

Answer (score 2):

What you might do is use the recursive pattern to recurse the first subpattern using `(?1)` to match all the parenthesis so the split does not split inside the parenthesis as well and use [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex).

Then split on a comma followed by 0+ horizontal whitespace chars

```
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|,\h*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wzvf1C/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/uZNg5)

```
$re = '/(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|,\h*/';
$strings = [
    "Test A, Test B, Test C (data1, data1)",
    "Test A, Test B, Test C (data1, data1), Test D (data1, data1), Test E (data1, data1(data, data))",
    "Test A, Test B, Test C (data1, data1), Test D (data1, data1), Test E ((data1, data1))"
];

foreach($strings as $s) {
    print_r(preg_split($re, $s));
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test A
    [1] => Test B
    [2] => Test C (data1, data1)
)
Array
(
    [0] => Test A
    [1] => Test B
    [2] => Test C (data1, data1)
    [3] => Test D (data1, data1)
    [4] => Test E (data1, data1(data, data))
)
Array
(
    [0] => Test A
    [1] => Test B
    [2] => Test C (data1, data1)
    [3] => Test D (data1, data1)
    [4] => Test E ((data1, data1))
)
```